# Coding the filter function definition in SML

Tags: filter, sml

I am trying to code the filter definition in sml without using `filter`.  I almost have the code working.  I just can't figure out the return value of the `if` statement when x is not < 5.

Here's my code:

```
fun Filter[] = [] | Filter(x::xs) =
let
 fun lessthan x = if x < 5 then x else 0 
in
  lessthan(x)::Filter(xs)
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: If you are trying to "code the filter definition" then why are you hard-wiring in a specific predicate (`x < 5`)? The `filter` function has uses beyond returning elements less that 5 in a list. `List.filter` has type `fn : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list` but you seem to be trying to make a function of type `int list -> int.list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John Coleman said, a filter function should take its predicate (an `'a -> bool` function) as an input argument and call that rather than a built-in predicate. Otherwise your filter function will only work for very specific things and you need to re-define it all the time.

You want to, essentially, include `x` in the result only if some condition is true. So you can't write `lessthan(x)::Filter(xs)`, since that'd mean it always gets included. You're currently trying to "not include it" by having `lessthan(x)` return `0`. But that means the result gets cluttered with zeros that you cannot distinguish from *real* zeros.

E.g.: `Filter [0,1,6]` becomes `[0,1,0]`; now you no longer know which zero was a zero before filtering. Ideally, filtering should give you `[0,1]` in this example.

Hints:

- Move the *if-then-else* into the main definition of `Filter` rather than in the predicate.
- Only use the `::` operator in the true branch. But call `Filter` in both branches.
- Here's a template:

  ```
  fun filter p [] = []
    | filter p (x::xs) =
        if (* some condition that shouldn't just be 'lessthan' *)
        then (* something with '::' and also with 'x' and 'filter p xs' *)
        else (* something without '::' but still with 'filter p xs' *)
  ```

  You could then call that code like:

  ```
  - fun lessthan5 x = x < 5;
  - filter lessthan5 [0,3,5,9];
  > val it = [0,3] : int list
  ```

  Or using an anonymous function:

  ```
  - filter (fn x => x < 5) [0,3,5,9];
  > val it = [0,3] : int list
  ```

Comment: does this template use pattern matching?

Comment: @kekundel: It uses pattern matching on the list: The first `[]` is a pattern that matches the empty list, in which case the filtering is trivially the empty list (no items that could be removed), and `x::xs` is a pattern that matches a non-empty list with the first element being `x` and the tail being `xs`, in which case there is potentially some filtering to be done (should `x` be included?) and some recursive calling (`xs` should be filtered, too). So yes, there is pattern matching.